# How do you add your eclipse view plugin to a specific pre-existing JDT views category?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, categories

I wrote a new eclipse view plugin and when you select Window -> Show View --> Other
you can see it in its own folder/category (the view defines a new category)

Is it possible to code the plugin.xml of this view so that when the user clicks on Show View
the view is shown in one of the preexisting JDT folders/categories, like "Java" or "Java Browsing"?
if so, assuming i just need to specify the preexisting category's id
in my view's 'category' attribute, where can one find the list of JDT view categories and their associated ID's?

More Info:
my plugin.xml contains this:

```
<category
        name="MyCat"
        id="com.mine">
</category>
```

which specifies in which category the view will show. so, when deployed, the user can add my new view by: Window - Show View - Other
and there, among all pre-existing categories/folders, the user will see my category
"MyCat" and when opened, it contains my newly developed/contributed view.

my back to my question... i don't want to create a new category, but instead, i want my
new view to show in the existing Java category. can i do that and if so how?
i assume that, if it is possible to do, i would probably need to 1) not use the 'name' attribute in my 'category'
element, and 2) the 'id' attribute should contain the id of the Java category.
(which is what?).
so perhaps there is a place where all pre-existing jdt view categories 
are defined, but i couldn't find it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a perspective extension with your views. Here is an example with the debug perspective 
[org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_advext_perspectiveExtension.htm)

The category for Java is org.eclipse.jdt.ui.java

Comment: thanks, but your answer/example shows how to include my new view in some perspective. i already have a perspective extension defined (JavaPerspective). that's not what i'm asking